# Tika Server 1.10 - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: apache-tika

How can I configure the underlying nginx server of the tika server?

I have to increase the size client_max_body_size directive.

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? And what makes you think there's a copy of nginx anywhere involved in Tika? (By default there certainly isn't!)

Comment: I run the tika-server (https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS#Running_the_Tika_Server). The response error message is: "413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.8.0". That's why I concluded.

Comment: Have you perhaps put a copy of nginx in front of Tika? Only Tika is pure-Java, no nginx in sight!

Comment: Oh that's probably AWS running the docker container of the tika-server. Sorry for my foolishness.